# Tmux with non-alphanumeric prefix

Tags: tmux

I have tmux 1.5 installed on a couple of Ubuntu machines and I have this in my ~/.tmux.conf:

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-\
```

So, on a couple of RedHat machines I have ssh access to (but not root) I compiled tmux 1.6 and installed it in my directory. Now when I try to set C-\ as my prefix, I get this on startup:

```
 /home/user/.tmux.conf: 2: line continuation at end of file
```

Obviously its not parsing the file correctly.  As a test I change it to:

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-'
```

And I get:

```
 /home/user/.tmux.conf: 2: invalid or unknown command: set-option -g prefix C-'
```

So it's still not parsing correctly.

However, this does work:

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-o
```

So it seems to be a problem with non-alphanumeric keys.

any ideas>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In *tmux* 1.6 a backslash at the end of a configuration line acts as a line continuation character. You can arrange to get the backslash to the command itself in several ways:

Simply make sure it is not the last character. Put a space after it, or a space and a comment:

```
set-option -g prefix C-\ # (not a line continuation!)
```

Wrap it in single quotes:

```
set-option -g prefix 'C-\'
```

Wrap it in double quotes (and escape it, since backslash is special inside double quotes):

```
set-option -g prefix "C-\\"
```

---

Your `C-'` was failing because the single quote was starting a quoted string (the error message is not so helpful here).

Also, there is no standard control character or sequence for <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd>, so *tmux* would have complained (`bad key: C-'`) even if you had double quoted it to get it past the initial parsing stage; there are only a handful of non-alphabetic [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters): `@[\]^_?`.

Comment: Yep that worked fine! I figured it was a feature of the new version.

Comment: How can I assign `<` character for prefix?. I am using Turkish keyboard and I am trying `set -g prefix 'C-<'` but I am getting bad key error.

Comment: @mesuutt: *C-<* is not a standard control character (see the last paragraph of the answer). Versions of *tmux* before 1.8 do not support it at all (giving the “bad key” message); starting with 1.8, *tmux* will recognize it, but only via xterm-style modifyOtherKeys sequences (e.g. `ESC [27;5;60~` for *C-<*), which your terminal emulator may or may not support.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen I am using zsh and tmux 1.8. I cant understand exactly what you mean. What should I write to .tmux.conf for change prefix to C-< ? What is the `ESC [27;5;60~` ?

Comment: @mesuutt: I can successfully do `set -g prefix 'C-<'` when using *tmux* 1.8 (I do not get the “bad key” message that 1.7 and earlier give); your shell does not much matter. That escape sequence is what *tmux* will recognize as *C-<*, so your terminal needs to send those eight bytes when you press *C-<* (*tmux* asks for this behavior by sending another sequence when it starts, but not all terminal emulators support it). Try typing *C-<* after running `printf '\e[>4;1m';cat` **outside** *tmux*; if you do not get the sequence, then your terminal probably does not have the necessary support.